# Scheduled notification not appearing andriod 13

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, notifications

Im trying to show a notification at scheduled times but no matter what code i use it is not working.

This is the Mainactivity.java:

```
    package com.sbr.go;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlarmManager;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.NotificationChannel;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.media.AudioAttributes;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
    import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
    
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.LoadAdError;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAdLoadCallback;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static WebView WebView;
    WebView webView;


    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    private final static int FCR=1;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    //private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 123;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> fileUploadCallback;
    //private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE = 112;

    //private final int FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE = 1;
    public Uri imageUri;

    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    WebView view;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //NotificationUtils.scheduleMonthlyNotification(this);
        NotificationUtils.triggerNotification(this);

        //*//Admob BANNER من هنا//*// يمسح السلاشات من اسفل لتفعيل الاعلانات
        //AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.admob_id);
        //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        //.setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();

        //adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        //Admob BANNER من هنا//

// Initialize the InterstitialAd object
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        InterstitialAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-1851250777225639/563222258", adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                // Ad loaded successfully
                mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                mInterstitialAd = null;
            }
        });



        // Show the interstitial ad if it is ready.

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        progressBar= (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipelayout);
        final WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.refresh,R.color.refresh1,R.color.refresh2);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                browser.reload();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);





                    }
                },20000);
            }
        });
        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        //mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        //webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);//
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        //webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);



        // For API level below 18 (This method was deprecated in API level 18)
        webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        //webView.setWebViewClient(null); ////السطر ده بيخلي اي لينك يفتح بره من خلال كروم
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        // Use remote resource
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()

                {//---Da Ely Be5aly urls load externally in google chrome// begin
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                 //---Open links in the system browser
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
                }//---Da Ely Be5aly urls load externally in google chrome// end

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                try {
                    webView.stopLoading();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                }

                webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Check your internet connection and try again.");
                alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                        startActivity(getIntent());
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
                super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            }



            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
                    {
                if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
                }
                else {
                    // If the ad is not loaded, proceed with loading the WebView content
                    mInterstitialAd = null;
                }
                    }


            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }
                });

        {webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");}

    }



    // Prevent the back-button from closing the app
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class NotificationUtils {
        private NotificationManager _notificationManager;
        private Context _context;
        TextView view;
        public static void triggerNotification(Context context) {

        //public static void scheduleMonthlyNotification(Context context) {
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            long intervalMillis = 60 * 1000; // 1 minute in milliseconds

            Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            //Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            //calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            //calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 21);
            //calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14); // 6 AM
            //calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 52);
            //calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            //if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
             //   calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            //}

            //if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
               // alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            //} else {
               // alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
           // }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + intervalMillis, pendingIntent);
            } else {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + intervalMillis, pendingIntent);
            }
        }

        public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

            public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "10001" ;
            private final static String default_notification_channel_id = "default" ;
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                Intent repeating_intent =new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.setAction(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);


                PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,repeating_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,
                        default_notification_channel_id )
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable. ic_launcher_foreground )
                        .setContentTitle("Notification 1")
                        .setContentText("Hello");
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) ;
                if (Build.VERSION. SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES. O ) {
                    AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                            .setContentType(AudioAttributes. CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION )
                            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM )
                            .build() ;
                    int importance = NotificationManager. IMPORTANCE_HIGH ;
                    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new
                            NotificationChannel( NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID , "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME" , importance) ;
                    notificationChannel.enableLights( true ) ;
                    notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color. RED ) ;
                    notificationChannel.enableVibration( true ) ;
                    notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern( new long []{ 100 , 200 , 300 , 400 , 500 , 400 , 300 , 200 , 400 }) ;
                    mBuilder.setChannelId( NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID ) ;
                    assert mNotificationManager != null;
                    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel) ;
                }
                assert mNotificationManager != null;
                mNotificationManager.notify(( int ) System. currentTimeMillis (), mBuilder.build()) ;
                triggerNotification(context);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sabr.go" >

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RTG_SCHED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:extractNativeLibs="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <receiver
            android:name=".MainActivity$NotificationUtils$NotificationReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name="com.sabr.go.MainActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <!-- Add the following GoogleMobAds meta-data tag to the <application> section -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-1851250777225639~4560934561"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This line in the manifest:                 android:name=".MainActivity$NotificationUtils$NotificationReceiver"
Triggers a problem:
**This inner class should be static (com.sabr.go.MainActivity$NotificationUtils$NotificationReceiver)**

What might be the problem preventing the notification from working?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @bener07 would appreciate if you can help